# How to access karate ui automation driver details like sessionid in afterScenario?

Tags: karate

I am reading the json file which contains the array of configurations of browserstack browsers or devices on which I want run my UI automation tests and defining it in karate-config.js as a global variable, for ex: **config.envrironments**. That variable I am calling it in **Examples** Table as **envrironments** and using it in **dynamic scenario outline** to initialize driver for different browser/device sessions as **envrironments[__num]**. The execution is working fine as expected.

After execution, I want to call the browserstack api which updates the test scenario status as **passed** or **failed with a reason** in their dashboard or in the browserstack report integrated in jenkins for clear understanding. The api requires driver sessionId as api path param, status(passed or failed) and reason(if failed) as body.

I am able to get the status and reason from **karate.info.errorMessage** after configuring afterScenario for the feature. But my problem is to get the browserstack sessionId.

To get the driver.sessionId in afterScenario, i'm getting error as **"driver" is not defined**. I guess driver object is getting killed **in between each execution of scenario outline and the afterScenario**.

Is there any way to keep the driver alive until the afterScenario is completed?

or

any other alternatives like implementing ExecutionHook class or any other class through which we can get the driver details?

Please help. Thanks in advance.

UPDATE:

I'm using Java 8 and karate version 0.9.6

Below is my code:

Test Feature -

```
Feature: Test Feature

Background:
    * def scenarioStatus = 
    """
        {
            "status": "passed",
            "reason": ""
        }
    """
    * configure afterScenario = 
    """
        function(){
            if(karate.info.errorMessage){
                scenarioStatus.status = 'failed';
                scenarioStatus.reason = karate.info.errorMessage;
            }
            karate.log('session id : ' + karate.get('sessionId'));
            // karate.call('browserstack.feature', scenarioStatus);
        }
    """

@dummyMobileBrowser
Scenario Outline: Dummy Scenario
    * def browserTestName = karate.info.scenarioName + ' - '
    * call read('driver.feature@initializeDriver')
    * def sessionId = driver.sessionId
    * call read('loginPage.feature@login')


# I'm defining array of device or browser configs in karate-config.js

Examples:
| deviceConfigs |
```

driver.feature

```
Feature: Driver Related Feature

Background:
    * def jsUtils = read('classpath:jsUtils.js')
    * def getDriverConfig = 
    """
        function(){
            if(browserstack == "yes"){
                var configResult = karate.call('driver.feature@createBrowserStackConfig');
                var browserstackConfig = configResult.browserstackConfig;
                return browserstackConfig;
            }else{
                return deviceConfigs[__num];
            }
        }
    """

@initializeDriver
Scenario: Initialize Driver
    * def driverConfig = getDriverConfig()
    * configure driver = driverConfig
    * print 'Driver Config: ', driverConfig
    * driver envHost
    # also tried to def here
    # * def sessionId = driver.sessionId
    # * eval scenarioStatus.browserstackSessionId = sessionId
    # * karate.write(sessionId, 'classpath:browserstackSessionId.txt')
    * driver.fullscreen()

@takeScreenshot
Scenario: Take screenshot
    * driver.screenshot()

@createBrowserStackConfig
Scenario: Create Browserstack Config
    * def deviceCapabilities = deviceConfigs[__num]
    * def driverUrl = 'https://' + browserstackUsername + ':' + browserstackKey + '@' + browserstackUrl + '/wd/hub'
    * eval commonCapabilities.build = (karate.match(typeof browserstackBuildName, 'undefined').pass) ? commonCapabilities.build + currentEpochTime : browserstackBuildName
    * def desiredCapabilities = karate.merge(deviceCapabilities, commonCapabilities)
    * def driverType = (karate.match(desiredCapabilities.browserName, "#notnull").pass) ? desiredCapabilities.browserName : desiredCapabilities.browser + 'driver'
    * eval driverType = (karate.match(driverType, 'firefoxdriver').pass) ?  'geckodriver' : driverType
    * eval desiredCapabilities.name = (karate.match(desiredCapabilities.browserName, "#notnull").pass) ? desiredCapabilities.browserName : desiredCapabilities.browser
    * eval desiredCapabilities.name = browserTestName + desiredCapabilities.name
    * def capabilities = karate.merge(deviceCapabilities, commonCapabilities)
    * eval capabilities.name = (karate.match(capabilities.browserName, "#notnull").pass) ? capabilities.browserName : capabilities.browser
    * eval capabilities.name = browserTestName + capabilities.name
    * def browserSession = { desiredCapabilities: '#(desiredCapabilities)', capabilities: '#(capabilities)' }
    * def browserstackConfig = { type: '#(driverType)', webDriverSession: '#(browserSession)', start: false, webDriverUrl: '#(driverUrl)' }
```

Answer (score 0):

Even if the `driver` is not callable - you should be able to access variables, right ?

So if you did this within the normal test-flow:

```
* def sessionId = driver.sessionId
```

Then the `sessionId` variable should be directly accessible in the after-hooks. Do `karate.get('sessionId')` if needed, try it and please comment below if it works.

Comment: I have updated my code snippet. Please check. I tried like you mentioned. I am getting null when I am trying to log in afterScenario which is defined in Background.

Comment: @YatheendraBC okay I give up. it may depend on which version of karate etc. so please follow this process (exactly as documented) and we will try to look at it: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue - but please note that ideally we want people like you to contribute code, that is what an open-source project needs most

Comment: Thanks. For a temporary workaround, I'm writing the sessionId to a file via Java and reading it in afterScenario to update the test status to browserstack.